# subprocess.run()'s output is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Below is the command:

```
    try:
        op = subprocess.run(['docker', 'login', '-u', 'username', '-p', 'password', 'dockerhub.com'], check=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        print("Docker stdout :", op.stdout)
        print("Docker Error :", op.stderr.decode("utf-8"))
    except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

It's working good, when the right password is provided and the 2 print statements are working as expected.

```
Login Succeeded
Docker stdout : None
Docker Error :
```

In case of incorrect password, I would like to capture the output as seen while running on the shell(bash), like below:

`Error response from daemon: Get https://dockerhub.com/v2/: unknown: Bad credentials`

instead I receive the traceback, where the above error message is not seen.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scripts/test.py", line 54, in my_func
    op = subprocess.run(['docker', 'login', '-u', 'username', '-p', 'incorrectpassword', 'dockerhub.com'], check=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['docker', 'login', '-u', 'username', '-p', 'incorrectpassword', 'dockerhub.com']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The title is confusing IMHO, since you give one example where you have output, and one example where you get an Exception. However, the title says "output is empty"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also catch the [*`subprocess.CalledProcessError`* Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError). Attributes of that exception hold the arguments, the [exit code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError.returncode), and [stdout and stderr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError.stderr) if they were captured.

```
try:
    op = subprocess.run(['docker', 'login', '-u', 'username', '-p', 'password', 'dockerhub.com'], check=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print("Docker stdout :", op.stdout)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    exit_code = e.returncode
    stderror = e.stderr
    print(exit_code, stderror)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. it will fail & exit the script at this point, if am not wrong ?
I mean, script wont be further processed correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks:

**1:** You called `subprocess.run()` with `check=True`. This causes the exception that you observed.

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

> If *check* is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a `CalledProcessError` exception will be raised. Attributes of that exception hold the arguments, the exit code, and stdout and stderr if they were captured.

The simples solution is to use `check=False` (which is the default value, so you could just reove that argument). Then, after `subprocess.run()` has completed, check `op.returncode` and `op.stderr`.

Alternatively, you could use `check=True` and catch the exception, which was also mentioned in other answers.

**2**: You used `stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.

This will print the standard output of the process to the standard output of the system (i.e., the console). If you want to capture the standard output, you should use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` instead (or use `capture_output=True`, which is an alternative way to set the `stdout` and `stderr` arguments).

Answer (score -2):

try this ( add capture_output=True )

```
try:
    op = subprocess.run(['docker', 'login', '-u', 'username', '-p', 'password', 'dockerhub.com'], check=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,capture_output=True)
    print("Docker stdout :", op.stdout)
    print("Docker Error :", op.stderr.decode("utf-8"))
except:
traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: My bad, I didnt add that as part of the question.

Yes, I tried that as well, but throws an error like below

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'`

Comment: `capture_output` requires Python version 3.7 or higher, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: docs clearly state: "The *stdout* and *stderr* arguments may ***not be supplied at the same time as*** *capture_output*."